# script to launch new window in tmux as another user

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, tmux

I have the following in my new.sh bash file -

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo -u bobby tmux -2 new-session -A -s main
sudo -u bobby tmux new-window `cd /home/new_dir/; node n1.js`
sudo -u bobby tmux new-window `cd /home/new_dir/; node n2.js`
sudo -u bobby tmux detach
```

I run `new.sh` as `root` user, but I encounter a lot of problems: 
 
1. tmux opens up for `root` user, and does not detach automatically, even though I have tmux detach. 
 
2. Why does tmux open for user `root`, when it is created for user `bobby` (this is verified by `tmux ls` command. It says `empty server` for user `root`, and shows a session for user `bobby`) 
 
3. The command after tmux new-window `cd home/new_dir/; node n1.js` and `cd home/new_dir/; node n2.js` is completely ignored!

Answer (score 0):

the command between backquote is expanded in current shell and expanded to its output mayb you wanted the command between single quotes.

Comment: When I use `'` or `"`, same thing happens!